# NSWindow not resizing to fit NSView - SOMETIMES?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm having trouble resizing an NSWindow to fit an NSView. It must be a logic error as it works but not for one action.

I have one NSWindow which is empty, and 3 NSViews with components and are different sizes.

With the following code I resize the NSWindow to fit the NSView and display it:

```
[_window setContentSize:_mainView.frame.size];
[_window setContentView:_mainView];
```

This code works fine.

However in one NSView I have a Back button, and while this displays the correct NSView in the NSWindow, it does not re-size it back. As an example the initial window is a certain size, I click to switch to another view and it resizes correctly, I press the back button, the NSView is displayed but the window stays the same size?

Can anyone explain to me why when I switch back to the original NSView, it doesn't resize the NSWindow?

Thanks in advance everyone. This is the complete code I have:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [_window setContentSize:_mainView.frame.size];
    [_window setContentView:_mainView];
}

- (IBAction)switchSubtractionView:(id)sender {
    [_window setContentSize:_subtractionView.frame.size];
    [_window setContentView:_subtractionView];
}

- (IBAction)switchAdditionView:(id)sender {
    [_window setContentSize:_additionView.frame.size];
    [_window setContentView:_additionView];
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// THE FOLLOWING METHOD DISPLAYS THE NEW VIEW CORRECTLY BUT DOESN'T RESIZE
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
- (IBAction)switchMainMenu:(id)sender {
    [_window setContentSize:_mainView.frame.size];
    [_window setContentView:_mainView];
}
```

Thanks in advance everyone.

EDIT: it seems to me that when getting VIEW.frame.size, if this is repeatedly used, it loses its values? This seems very strange behaviour to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A window's content view must always be sized to fill the window's content area.  Therefore, when you set the window's content size, you effectively change the size of the current content view.  This happens just before you switch the content view, so you are changing the size of the old view.

Try setting the content view to a new, disposable NSView before changing the content size, and then setting the new content view.

Comment: thanks so much for the response, but I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. I have the _mainView, _additionView, etc set as NSViews, how do I create a new disposable NSView? Thanks again

Comment: `NSView* view = [[NSView alloc] initWithSize:someSize];`

Comment: if i understand the answer correctly, I create a new NSView with the default size, then change the view to the view I want, and then change the size?

Comment: @Cristian he simply means change the order of your `setContentSize` and `setContentView` calls.

Comment: @trojanfoe if I do that then the views don't get resized at all

Comment: I can fix the problem by settings CGSize variables for each view as the application launched and that fixes the problem, so the issue is that the view.frame.size changes when you change views. Switching the setContentSize and setContentView displays the views, but does not resize them. Surely there is a better way than having to set the sizes in stone?

Comment: @Cristian My mistake - he doesn't mean that at all.  He means do what Rob Keniger has suggested - set a dummy view as the content view with the specified size and then set the real view.

Comment: the declaration initWithSize does not exist?

Comment: i've got it working with the dummy NSView, but it doesn't seem right, is there no way to resize an NSWindow to fit the View without reisizing the view itself?

Comment: @Cristian, another way to go is to not change the window's content view, but instead install your views as the only subview of the content view. You would leave the window with its default, plain content view.  Then, you would make sure that your views have their auto-resize masks set so that they are not resized when their superview changes size. For example, you could pin them to the top and the left, unpin them on the right and bottom, and don't allow them to vary in width or height.

Comment: @KenThomases that sounds like a good idea but surely that requires more processing power?

Comment: Huh? Processing power? For what?